# AutoMapper Asp.Net Core 2: Unmapped Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When trying to map my Dto to my model, I am getting an error that certain properties are not being mapped.

> **Unmapped properties:**
>   Id
>   AddressId
>   ContactId
>   Barns
>   Gateways
>   UserFarms

But the Id is supposed to be auto-generated, the AddressId, ContactId, and Barns are nullable properties.
The issue occurs when I get to `var farmToCreate = _mapper.Map<Farm>(farmForCreateDto);` within the controller. <strike>It tries to log the user activity which runs a `SaveChangesAsync` on the database, and, at that point, throws an error that it can't map the Farm Dto to its Model due to unmapped properties.</strike>

---

#### FarmsController.cs

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FarmsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBaseRepository _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public FarmsController(IBaseRepository repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost("createFarm")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFarm([FromBody] FarmForCreateDto farmForCreateDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        Address createdFarmAddress = null;

        if (farmForCreateDto.Address != null)
        {
            var farmAddressToCreate = _mapper.Map<Address>(farmForCreateDto.Address);

            createdFarmAddress = await _repo.CreateAddress(farmAddressToCreate);
        }

        Address createdFarmContactAddress = null;

        if (farmForCreateDto.Contact.Address != null)
        {
            var farmContactAddressToCreate = _mapper.Map<Address>(farmForCreateDto.Contact.Address);

            createdFarmContactAddress = await _repo.CreateAddress(farmContactAddressToCreate);
        }

        Contact createdFarmContact = null;

        if (farmForCreateDto.Contact != null)
        {
            var farmContactToCreate = _mapper.Map<Contact>(farmForCreateDto.Contact);

            farmContactToCreate.Address = createdFarmContactAddress;

            createdFarmContact = await _repo.CreateContact(farmContactToCreate);
        }

        var farmToCreate = _mapper.Map<Farm>(farmForCreateDto);

        farmToCreate.Address = createdFarmAddress;
        farmToCreate.Contact = createdFarmContact;

        var createdFarm = await _repo.CreateFarm(farmToCreate);

        var farmToReturn = _mapper.Map<FarmForDetailedDto>(createdFarm);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetFarm", new { controller = "Farms", id = createdFarm.Id }, farmToReturn);
    }
```

#### Models\Farm.cs

```
public class Farm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public int? AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Barn> Barns { get; set; }
}
```

#### Dtos\FarmForCreateDto.cs

```
public class FarmForCreateDto
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Models.Account Account { get; set; }

    public ContactForCreateDto Contact { get; set; }

    public AddressForCreateDto Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you try to configure mappings? http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Comment: Gah! I knew I was forgetting something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure mappings.

[How to configure mappings](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html)